# How to remove bootstrap in Volt, the new ruby framework

Tags: voltrb

I'm getting this error while trying to launch the server.

> /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/volt-0.8.26/lib/volt/server/rack/asset_files.rb:38:in `component': Unable to find component 'bootstrap', make sure the gem is included in your Gemfile (RuntimeError)

I removed these two gems:

gem 'volt-bootstrap'

gem 'volt-bootstrap-jumbotron-theme'strong text**

Answer (score 2):

If you look in app/main/config/dependencies.rb you'll see

```
component 'bootstrap'
```

Just remove that.  Check out the [docs on components](http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/components.html) for more information.